# Ui-router para sistemas com muitos modulos

Tags: angularjs, ui-router

Me deparei com um problema tenho um Controller chamado OrderController que está em dois modulos, Sales e Supply. Quando faço a rota para a tela que vai usar esse controller como posso definir qual dos dois controllers eu quero usar, como posso definir de qual modulo eu quero o controller? tentei registrar a rota separadamente em cada modulo, mas mesmo assim não da certo.

Código completo:
https://plnkr.co/edit/iLUuUNKWZJhg23rrk1zB?p=preview

Comment: acho que você deve mudar o nome do controller, ou ele irá usar o que foi declarado primeiro.

Comment: @CelsomTrindade está correto. Utilize nomes diferentes, ou declare o controller apenas uma vez.

Comment: então os modules do angular não servem como um namespace ou packge de uma "classe"

Comment: @RicardoCarvalho não. Referência: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14909537/1845714

Comment: @OnoSendei obrigado pela referência. Fico triste, mas se é o jeito, vamos fazer assim :/

Comment: @RicardoCarvalho não por isso. Certamente é uma limitação, porém não muito impactante.

Answer (score 1):

Não seria melhor que cada módulo tivesse seu próprio `controller`, cada um com seu próprio nome e a lógica que deve ser compartilhada entre os dois `controllers` ficar em um `service`?

**Exemplo:**

```
angular
  .module('sales.module',[])
  .controller('SalesController',SalesController);

angular
  .module('suply.module',[])
  .controller('SuplyController',SuplyController);

angular
   .module('outro.module',[])
   .service('OrderService',OrderService)
```

Ou você pode por essa lógica em um controller pai e esses outros dois herdam o controller pai.